# insert text to imageview (and generate new image file) by drag-drop gesture

Tags: android, image-processing, drag-and-drop, imageview

**Note** : To avoid miss-communication, i need to generate a new image file with the drag-dropped text so its not just a simple text on the ImageView.

My goal is to let my user insert a text by drag and drop it to the ImageView and generate the new image file (PNG) so user will have a new image file with a text on it.

I have managed to insert the text and generate the new image file, but the problem is the text is currently hard-coded and not drag-drop.

This is my simplified code on my custom ImageView:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint text = new Paint();
    text.setColor(Color.RED);
    text.setTextSize(32);

    float x = imgWidth / 2 - txtWidth / 2;
    float y = imgHeight / 2 - 16;

    // canvas.drawPaint(text);
    canvas.drawText("TESTTTTTTTT", x, y, text);
}
```

The code above is working because i just manually insert the text in the center just after the ImageView is created.

Now, my problem is i have no idea how to get the same result, but this time i want the user to drag-drop the text and place it anywhere on the ImageView (and finally generate a new image file) instead of hard-coded the text in the center of the ImageView like i did.

Thanks for your help, please ask me if you have some questions.

Comment: have you tried adding ontouch event listener for textview to get drag and drop and final position of the textview, to use as a co-ordinate in your `ondraw` method?

Comment: Yes, but i stuck on the co-ordinate the last position of the text to the image. How can i call the onDraw method or do something like that so the canvas can draw my textview? Thanks

Comment: Can you please post your `onTouchListener` code.

Comment: @Pr38y Thanks, i solved it by using andrid's drag-drop library instead of ontouchlistener. The onDraw method is automatically called

Comment: please share ur solution with us.Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell me which library you used?